# How to read NFC Snoop Log on Android?

Tags: android

On Android I can dump the state of the NFC hardware with

```
> adb shell dumpsys nfc
```

This generates some output and at the end there's a snoop log:

```
--- BEGIN:NFCSNOOP_LOG_SUMMARY (6009 bytes in) ---
ASJeKl5VrwUAeJyt2H9wVEcdAPDvvn33Lne53OUuR5LLhSQHCT8DcVIIQbAQTAuiEYMV65COBmgcTYuF1NYOCqFJUQZbEBTq0JZrAacWZUoZIIygEJm2yBRG2ynS0iIQ
px2tFE1rB3/k3Pfu9vvd3fb6l2GAl729z35397s/7mzwfmqAgQM75wOwucChWPyNeuUMKqF/qlvMEsDDFhQAs3jvg339VgfPWGC3RFl5EcxuDQKkIMhtbvk45xaLwsWY
C1hhq72AjWS8n9uZ34ZaFx4DjNkQqRFyi2jbBzdF3UYsC8TznErxPA8sYAUwv048LwMfE2+AANR5UdkOZ8xizA+LZ7pvs23IMM7hlULxKgdfCJLgvS2w3mK9LC3aCsHL
0WyRJYtsqM6FItqc6M+1Kd6/SYTIOFgOvJ0ST18TrYk/8K2irO7ASEwp/iCUrc2hLeBV4A4UNygV2qd7FYIc/p2tUOjA+xOUCismS2FlkRR2JZQKp8Z7FUQPLxTICsON
SoVVpV4Fx4Hn/e4Acc7S19tg40l3dPhCEL/dAhn42J9rIgAOSq0hs4Z42YFHk7IBfwD+tsBrwBEN+Jn47wqTL7YG4PNT8MVWd4gPeHMncmNxAXRUeK/5gC1mtgPnfUrU
+xv+31HHYfM9D4sEFVnpjlZLWvzjjRvz2RD7opuEIrsq4H0vQquMTYzf2nU3YzHL8me4BdxmK0T/imBGNqeDvJHVNDP2BbdbzgTK3MB0+VwK28QMQoqXBETmimTlzCfy
bj1z2D0i8zPulLdwBjac+tKCIKQc9/EPfW6peAzCn7Mt+a1sSz4YWyzpAjgOHu2zXNCG14oRu+ZOfxbrDiP2DWZgT4QJ265jB0sQW+lWyGKzKxCbxg2sLU5Yv449EkPs
90GM7OsliB0bZWAvRgl7SMeWlCJ2eeDJaA47MRWx5Sb26CjCHtSx7ghihwowskdGIfa5IgMLKhOwTsdupQm4fCwmMXtSDnOg/Q4P42wi+GF10PvFZgnGgrl9VmmnbiLl
02VlV5xVLp9jsCbbfsSfzS3KqydojH4XwG6lJmO3xpp5taGa2HU8D3v7OGTPTj/E5GjNRTYTNdhjVTRaFtNGa0wZYkdo6D9TjNgnywzsASUp/qhjx2jop825WpbDXpyJ
2Jy4gf0lkjddN8cR+3ktRjajGbG/2wY2rGDrdWxfFLFP35v4UFIE4aoZmaNgP9axTdTNN2iJQ4xy3zKwPiVd0zr2agqxmruYXEgvUJIsSn3M5rNZx7oqEPNFMLIlFNkz
ZmRWJWFDOlY3GrGrTYMS2/UpxI7+x8CeHU3pG7TypO8AsT8JY4xbxyLbnzRYFiP2hXyL7SB1/dnb7rVzbLiaSXbhNIOdl6KuZ/Suv3szYq00w60RjLHBZ2CPK6visI4l
JyF2dyIpsXdoVewxN/FiBZvM9UlJIpZ2MLKrCcRmlBjYgHIiLNOxmbRBDV94ZW8Oe6sdsQ2VBvacEtlOvZsjtF530Ly+RzvJy2butZYQtl/Heuis2t/RIfe4S3S8fHaM
gR0dlXeJ7aH1upZjZFU0m7Z5JB8eTdg2HVtKR/KNo2GJrS5F7OAiA7tYTOl7Il/6/rMa2f/6MMY0zetWc1O/EiX2HTsPe64c2dlNPaU5dtNpZJ0pBtuldL1P73o15d6k
MoxxFV1tBiLmjlxN2G907G0684f+MShnuHkcHY7m9v6Uck/6jo7dSdv7GBq9+yiy183R+22SsL/q2EbKvbvO10tsmCJbYCby2FjeRB6i3AvbGFlvOWIPVRnY5XrCfqpj
a2iJ9Y97T67X09MRA3PMOssJ26hjd9Din0JjNpP24WEzsu8q3dyqY8cpsu5rXGJfobvlwHIDey1O6bs731nxZBOyi0IY4xa6/54sNdgDymK7lG+xnadLzzNDgUCObVuD
bH3AYF9S9r3retcZ5V66BGM8TGfu82buPaAc4K/rWCNNSiKzYV4O4+MR+1nCwEYr95TH9evY05WIrSvEyObHEXvLvO6+OV5JF1vDYnTrTJ+bJbGOVsSeizPjo0gFTUU6
32XWT/veDrp/XmlCtmmSeRsoIbaN5WGb25BNhj7hz7H3NyBbYh6TlcoxebPe9et0RUvTB6ezUcRumPf4LcpKeUmf4VW0IbQfuFSYw8poDW8vN7BfKrn3lI7V0AwH6Z5y
E83wOXOrGlG6adxTliYQC/2iVGJv0pn7bfMj3Q+Ubm7SsTB1cyN99vmAztxax8AGE4R9T8cm0MHz6vEEsE6/+4XVDfcrDfEoSot/VCtLt8Wx9LGdTJaGSrH09BYs/SaV
1u/D0s3lWDq7OyhDP0ULetAchz1K6Pfra7CXQq+i/X9pkj4SzTKwJcqgHtLHYW0dYk/vmyqxDfRZ4aw5qC1JWiy/zrdY7qtC9gxgjF+mxVJn3sgPJoidn4/dTslZtTWU
Hd0I7HZvl52+ELPs3gyDXvFbrw92dbmljsUtGy6GcPz/NQ3krHR2O7I03sCl1jP+wxqHr64UkwkQ5fCrbrdD7reHy8VMel/RgXv6F8WxuTPU3PdPxiTcVf9R8O4VkINr
b5PwEVDgE3sLEW6MIjxyJSjhZYmPgv1dEi5fKuHHHAVuPOJHeG4Nwg1/6gnl5mvHNpyveebxdUk5cX5o3LTDOEvNtIUspGxfbW5ug8o9zFiob9CqX93jk1gfHV+n7zSw
tUqC5v1sl6IN+EwSY3y3E9m95hF7IUJsbb4EPSU3vP8BEZ41ZA==
--- END:NFCSNOOP_LOG_SUMMARY ---
```

I am interested to read this file content, because I hope to find all low-level NFC communication.

I think that this content is base64 encoded, but when I pass it through a decoder it's still glibberish:

```
> base64 --decode -i nfc_snoop_log_base64.txt -o nfc_snoop_log.txt
```

(Unfortunately I can't publish the output, since it contains characters which are not accepted by SO.)

From the sourcecode which generates this log (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/nfc/+/master/src/adaptation/debug_nfcsnoop.cc), I have the feeling that the content is compressed as well, but when I try to unzip it, I get an error:

```
> base64 --decode -i nfc_snoop_log_base64.txt -o nfc_snoop_log.zip
> unzip nfc_snoop_log.zip

Archive:  nfc_snoop_log.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of nfc_snoop_log.zip or
        nfc_snoop_log.zip.zip, and cannot find nfc_snoop_log.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Does anyone know, how to make the NFC snoop log human readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a fair bit of digging about in the code you linked from the Android source, the compression format used is Zlib. However, there's a NFCSnoop header appended to it after the compression. After decoding the base64, if you look at the first 9 bytes, you'll find the zlib header. That nfcsnoop header does carry the start time of the dump, which appears to be the start point of delta_time_ms later on. After removing the nfcsnoop header and running it through pigz with the -z parameter, you should have a decoded buffer.

The buffer is raw NFC packets, which consist of their own header as follows:
length, uint16
delta_time_ms, uint32
is_received, uint8

After that, you get data.

Edit: It appears these are NFC_HDR packets, which will need additional decoding using the NFC type details within Android.

Edit 2: Not NFC_HDR, apparently. NCI control packets.

Edit 3: I ended up writing a program to decode it, as I needed to do so myself.

It's located here: https://github.com/VivoKey/NFCSnoopDecoder

In short, it's a header, than length bytes of data after the header. Length is a uint16.